# Modelling nested models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I've been grappling with a problem which is proving to be quite hard. I've got a User model, a Photo model and a comment model. Now the way my website works is that a User can have many comments on a particular photo. On the reverse side, a comment can only belong to a particular user on a particular photo.

I've read through the Active Record Associations docs and from what I've gathered is that we can't use a `has_many :through` associations since it appears to work for polymorphic associations between models. I'm wondering if one can use `has_many :through` association on one side and `belongs_to` association on the reverse side.

Any tips, pointers and advice? I'm just beginning in Ruby on Rails

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work?

```
class User
  has_many :photos
  has_many :comments
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

User has many photos and comments (the ones he uploaded/written), and each comment belongs to user (writer) and a photo which was commented on.

Comment: This should solve the problem. I just finished wiriting exactly same code example! :P

Comment: But then when should one use `has_many :through` associations? And how do I access comments using these associations?

Comment: You'd use `has_many` with `through` option to specify the association table. You can find more details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: And how to access the comments?

Answer (score 1):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos
   has_many :comments, through: :photos #-> probably won't work but I'd try it first
end

#app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :comments do
       def current_user #-> photo.comments.current_user
          where user_id: self.user_id
       end
   end
end 

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :photo
   belongs_to :user
end
```

--

You could access the photo's comments as follows:

```
<% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
   <%= photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you wanted to show only the user's comments, you'd be able to use the `current_user` [ActiveRecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
<% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
   <%= photo.comments.current_user.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment %> #-> comments where user_id will be the same as photo's user_id
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: wow, what an epic answer. I'll try it just now and get back to you.

Comment: can you explain how the `current_user` method works? More specifically, what are we doing in `where user_id: self.user_id`?

Comment: It should pick out any comment which was written by the user who made the photo. IE the comment's `user_id` == `photo.user_id`

Comment: But many different users can comment on a photo, so wouldn't this hinder the other users from posting comments?

Comment: Nope, they'll be able to comment all they want. That method is meant to give you a way to *show* only the comments made by the photo's user. It's totally optional whether you use it or not

Comment: Oh I see, I will get back to you shortly

Comment: I just have one more question- How do I display a create form for comments. Should it be in the notes_controller or should I generate a separate controller for it. As of now I have a separate controller, but haven't written anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
User 
 has_many :comments

Photo
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user

Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :photo
```